# Eigenvalues of the $A+cB$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I know the maximum eigenvalue of the summation of Hermitian matrices (A+B), what is the maximal eigenvalue of  the matrix (A+cB), where c is any constant?

I need the solution in terms of the eigenvalues of (A+B), (A) or (B).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The maximum eigenvalue $e_{max}(M)$ of a Hermitian matrix $M$ is the maximum of $x^T M x$
for unit vectors $x$.  Since $\max(f + g) \le \max(f) + \max(g)$, this is 
a subadditive function on the Hermitian matrices.  So, for example, if $c > 1$
then $e_{max}(A+cB) \le e_{max}(A+B) + (c-1) e_{max}(B)$.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but is there any special cases that the inequality holds with equality. Actually, I am looking for the exact representation for the expression $e_max(A+cB)$

Comment: what you provide is the upper bound, what is the lower bound

Comment: It's an equality if $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvector for their maximum eigenvalues.

Comment: A lower bound is $e_{max}(A+B) \ge e_{max}(A) + e_{min}(B)$ (or the same with $A$ and $B$ interchanged).